# I am having Spring Boot REST API appilcation which has POST call when multiple users are calling this API I am facing data inconsistency

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, concurrency

```
> Following is the controller for post method

@Autowired
TrainerDetailsService trainerDetailsService;    
@RequestMapping(path="/saveTrainerDetails" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public TrainerDetails saveTrainerDetails(@RequestBody TrainerDetails trainerDetails)
{   
     trainerDetailsService.savetrainerDetails(trainerDetails);
     return trainerDetails;
}
```

> Service Layer

```
@Override
public TrainerDetails savetrainerDetails(TrainerDetails trainerDetails) {
    return trainerDetailsDao.saveTrainerDetails(trainerDetails);
}
```

> DAO Layer

@Override

```
public TrainerDetails saveTrainerDetails(TrainerDetails trainerDetails) {
        Transaction tr =null;
        try {
            Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tr =s.beginTransaction();
            s.saveOrUpdate(trainerDetails);
            tr.commit();
            s.flush();
            s.close();  
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return trainerDetails;
    }
```

> Also wanted to know how can i handle PUT request if multiple users are accessing it simultaneously

Comment: Multiple users is not a problem as long as your `trainerDetailsService` any other bean participating in the request processing is stateful.

Comment: Share the code for `trainerDetailsService` and any other bean involved like repo/dao

Comment: Do also check your transaction boundaries.

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar Did you mean stateless?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- yes. Noticed the typo. Couldn't modify my comment as it is older than 5 mins

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar Then it would be better to delete it and re-post it, rather than leaving a wrong comment like that.

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar Please check updated post

Answer (score 0):

You can try using @Transactional annotation on your Service class instead of handling the transaction manually.
Also, Isolation is not set as I see (unless there is more code than what's shown here).
From your issue, ISOLATION.READ_COMMITTED should be set.

Have a look at this article to understand these properties in more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation